# What are the uses of the modal verb "would"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, modal-verbs, conversation

Besides the future-in-past sense in conditional sentences, what other alternative uses can the word *would* have in conversation?

Comment: May I suggest you buy Swan, Practical English Usage? It's pretty indispensable at your level. It covers very well this subject.

Comment: Read the OED entry on the verb *will*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One application is the "past habitual."

*She ***would*** sing in the shower.*

See, e.g.,

[The Evolution of Grammar: Tense, Aspect, and Modality in the Languages of ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=aOvU6m-f1IwC&pg=PA156)
 By Joan Bybee, Revere Perkins, William Pagliuca

or:

[English Grammar: A function-based introduction, Volume 1](https://books.google.ca/books?id=TWZM1bFFMSkC&pg=PA161&dq=%22would%22%20english%20%22past%20habitual%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=2_MXVYcpzrWwBPWGgsgF&ved=0CDIQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22would%22%20english%20%22past%20habitual%22&f=false)
 By T. Givón

Another application is **dreaming/imagining in a past time**:

[Dusting Off the Ashes: One Man's Personal Journey Through ...](https://books.google.ca/books?id=5Wmc-hxcyP8C&pg=PA94&dq=%22in%20my%20dream%20I%20would%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=J_4XVer5GsbasASTzYLIBQ&ved=0CE0Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=%22in%20my%20dream%20I%20would%22&f=false)
Maria Heaton M.S., ‎Maria Heaton - 2010

**In my dream, I would keep saying** to them, “We need to leave the building. It is not good. It's not good.”

Comment: Dose your sentence mean " she used to sing in shower " ?

Comment: Yes, but see the difference in the 2nd book.

Answer (score 0):

What a good question- I would like to know as well!

("Would" is used in expressing the optative mood.)